# SQL - get the value of the related update by date

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have 2 tables

Orders:

```
> order_id, dollar_amount, purchase_date 
>
> 1         10             10-10-2020 
>
> 2         30             10-10-2020 
>
> 3         10             12-10-2020 
>
> 4         40             19-10-2020
```

And I have a table that contains updates of the dollar to pound values on various dates

```
> dollar_to_pound update_date
> 
> 1.3             10-10-2020
> 
> 1.5             11-10-2020
> 
> 0.9             15-10-2020
> 
> 1.2             20-10-2020
```

My goal is to query for the pound price, using the updated price for the time, so I get something like this

```
order_id    dollar_price pound_value calculated
> 1         10           1.3         13
>
> 2         30           1.3         39
>
> 3         10           1.5         15
>
> 4         40           0.9         36
```

How can I connect the 2 tables? Using equals won't work, as

Comment: Why won't equals work? `t1.purchase_date = t2.update_date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
SELECT o.order_id, 
    o.dollar_amount,
    d.dollar_to_pound,
    o.dollar_amount * d.dollar_to_pound AS calculated
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN dollar_to_pound_table d
ON d.update_date = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(update_date)
        FROM dollar_to_pound_table
        WHERE update_date <= o.purchase_date 
    );
```

Comment: I didn't know I can use inner queries on ON statements. This answer is the clearest of them all (though I think most answers I got will work)

Answer (score 0):

Use a join:

```sql
SELECT
    o.order_id,
    o.dollar_amount,
    r.dollar_to_pound AS pound_value
    o.dollar_amount * r.dollar_to_pound AS calculated
FROM Orders o
LEFT JOIN Rates r
    ON r.update_date = o.purchase_date
ORDER BY
    o.order_id;
```

The above query loosely assumes that the rates table would always be populated with all dates for which there were orders.  If not, then a given order might report `NULL` for the pound converted value.  You would need to define logic for how to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is script which calculate the closest rate date for order:

```
select t1.order_id,
t1.dollar_amount,
r.dollar_to_pound,
r.dollar_to_pound * t1.dollar_amount as 'pounds'
from (
select o.*,rates_to_date.max_date
from Orders o cross apply (select max(r.update_date) as max_date from Rates r where r.update_date <= o.purchase_date) rates_to_date) as t1 innner join Rates r on r.update_date = t1.max_date
```